# How can I access the alpha version of my Android app on Google Play?

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I just created a new app in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).  I haven't uploaded or published any beta or production APK's.  I've only uploaded an alpha version.

Once uploaded (and once several hours have passed), how/where can I find the alpha version of my app?  I can't seem to find it in the Google Play store on my phone.

Comment: I am interested to hear - how did you do it(or not do it)?

Comment: No luck, I haven't tried since posting this question.  If I figure it out, I'll update with an answer.

Comment: Any luck? I've had the same problem as well

Comment: any findings?? can't find any url to share

Answer (score 14):

You can provide access alpha version of app by following below steps:

1. Replace `com.package.name` with your app package name `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.package.name` ([Refer this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)), share this URL with your testers
2. After you open the URL page will have an option to "Become a tester", and proceed with the directions.

Note: Only members listed in the tester group can become a tester.

Comment: Perfect. Why is this information so difficult to find?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using alpha and beta testing features and I think they are one of the most important features of Google Play. Hope this answer helps anyone who needs to use those features:

Direct answer to your question: At Google Play, only alpha testers can see an application which is published at Alpha Testing Stage. (Also, only Beta Testers can see an application which is published at Beta Testing Stage)

Detailed steps:

1. At `Google Play Developer Console`, select your application and go
   to `APK` section.
2. Select `Alpha Testing` tab.
3. Upload your apk to `Alpha Testing`.
4. At `Google Play` an application which is published at `Alpha Testing` can only be seen by Alpha Testers. So you must define alpha tester groups.
5. Define tester group with `Manage list of testers` link at `Alpha Testing` tab. When you click that link you'll see a panel which asks; `Add Google Groups or Google+ Communities`.
6. If you don't have a group yet, you can [Create a Google+ Community](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2872671?hl=en) and add people to that group with
   their google/gmail accounts.
7. Testers are going to see your application at Google Play if they are
   logged in with the same google/gmail account which they are added as
   tester.

**NOTE:** Process is same for `Beta Testing`. Just define another tester group and add testers to it.

Comment: I'm guessing this answer is out of date, because google group and/or google+ integration is not required at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering this myself when I saw that this was a new feature. While I haven't tried it, my guess would be to add you account to the testing enabled devices. This can be found like this:

1. Settings button on the left side(the one that is a gear)
2. Account details
3. Gmail accounts with testing access - add you account to this and you will probably be able to see your app on Google Play(you might have to wait a few hours for a refresh, so give it a chance

Answer (score 0):

Have you published the app? Or just uploaded it?
You have enter some information and confirm publish restrictions, set the price, etc.
At the end you heve to press publish key on top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps,
1) Upload app in alpha
2) Add any group groups, Google+ groups
3) Publish the app and again come alpha page added group, you will have url which you need to give to your tester.

Hope this help you, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hi, I don't see an URL to give my testers. Here is the image of my apk page. 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11i02ti&s=8#
The red circle link is also not working..

Answer (score 0):

if you mean how/where can you find the alpha version of your app? I think you could find the Opt-in URL to see and download your app.

[image]